# Cell decomposition

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using probabilistic cell decomposition(2D&3D) for a path planning algorithm. It is possible to show the decomposition in RViz, which would be the solution programatically? - the cells dimensions can variate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10184/cell-decomposition/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can send [markers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) to `rviz` from your program. There are different markers available - lines, polygons, cubes, etc. The markers will probably be flexible enough to be able to represent the 2D and 3D data you are interested in.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on 2011-07-05**:
There is any solution to display the cubes or any point to be transparent so like this just the edges would be visible.Thank you.